# ¿Cómo obtener los últimos valores de unos artículos vendidos en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

**1. Tabla articulo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2. Tabla detalleingreso**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**3. Tabla detallaventa**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento la consulta que uso es la siguiente:

> SELECT DISTINCT nombre_art, detalle_ingreso.precio_compra FROM
> articulo JOIN detalle_ingreso WHERE articulo.id =
> detalle_ingreso.articulo_id

**Pero obtengo esto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

****LA IDEA ES OBTENER LOS DATOS CON EL ULTIMO PRECIO DE COMPRA DE LOS ARTICULOS SIN REPETIR****

Comment: Mas allá de que yo no almacenaría la cantidad como valor en una tabla sino que lo calcularía al momento contando todos los registros que van saliendo, tu duda al menos a mi no me termina de quedar clara

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien la diferencia entre `detalleingreso` y `detallaventa` pero, por lo que puedo entender de tu intento, da la sensación de que buscas algo así:

```
SELECT nombre_art,precio_compra
  FROM (
    SELECT articulo_id,
      MAX(venta_id) venta_id
      FROM detallaventa
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT nombre_art,
      precio_compra,venta_id
    FROM articulo
      JOIN detalle_ingreso
      ON articulo.id = 
      detalle_ingreso.articulo_id  
  ) c2 USING(articulo_id,venta_id);
```

Si lo que necesitas es obtener el último precio, necesariamente tienes que agrupar.

Pruébala y, si no te funciona, aporta tu dataset de pruebas en MySQL con phpmyadmin, exportar, y dejando las dudas en los comentarios. No te olvides de indicar el resultado que esperas para esos datos de muestra.